# What is the concept of being n-admissible used in the proof of the Iteration Theorem?

Tags: functions

I was trying to go through a proof of the Iteration Theorem from the book Number Systems and Foundations of Analysis from Mendelson when I came across the concept of n-admissible function.

The context is the following:

**Iteration Theorem:** Consider any Peano system $(P,S,1).$ Let $W$ be an arbitrary set, let $c$ be a fixed element of $W$, and let $g$ be a singulary opration on $W$. Then, there is a unique function $F:P \rightarrow W$ such that:

- $a) F(1) = c$
- $b) F(S(x)) = g(F(x))$ for all $x$ in $P$

**The Proof:** First, we shall prove the existence of a suitable function $F$. Take any $n$ in $P$. A function $f:A \rightarrow W$ is said to be **n-admissible** if and only if:

- Conditions on $A$:

1. $A \subseteq P$
2. $1 \in A$
3. $n \in A$
4. $(\forall u)(S(u) \in A \Rightarrow u \in A)$

- Conditions on $f$:

5. $f(1) = c$
6. $(\forall u)(S(u) \in A \Rightarrow f(S(u)) = g(f(u)))$

- $\textrm{I})$ If $f$ is $S(n)$-admissible, then $f$ is $n$-admissible.

Conditions (1),(2),(4)-(6) automatically go over from $S(n)$ to n. It only remain to check (3), that is to prove that $n \in A$. But, by assumption of $S(n)$-admissibility of $f$, $S(n) \in A$. But, then by (4), $n \in A$

- $\textrm{II})$ For any $n$ in $P$, there exist at least one $n$-admissible function.

We shall prove this by mathematical induction. Let $B$ be the set of all members of $n$ of $P$ for which there exist at least one $n$-admissible function. We must show that $B=P$. First $1 \in B$. Simply define the function $f$ with domain $\{1\}$ such that $f(1) = c.$ Clearly $f$ if $1$-admissible. Second assume $n \in B$. Then there is some $n$-admissible function $f$. Let $A$ be the domain of $f$. We define another function $f^*$ as follows: For any $x$ in $A$, let $f^*(x) = f(x)$, and, if $S(n) \notin A$, let $f^*(S(n)) = g(f(n))$. Note that, if $S(n) \in A$, then by (4), $f(S(n)) = g(f(n))$. Hence, in this case also, $f^*(S(n)) = g(f(n))$. The domain $A^*$ of $f^*$ is $A \cup \{S(n)\}$, which is equal to $A$ in the case where $S(n) \in A$. The verification that $f^*$ is $S(n)$-admissible is straightforward and is left as an exercise for the reader. Thus, $S(n) \in B$. We have shown that $n \in B \Rightarrow S(n) \in B$. By mathematical induction, $B=P$.

- $\textrm{III})$ If $f$ is $n$-admissible and $h$ is $n$-admissible, then $f(n) = h(n)$.

We shall prove this by mathematical induction. Let $Y = \{n : n \in P \land (\forall f)(\forall h)(f$ is $n$-admissible $\land \space h $ is $n$-admissible $\Rightarrow f(n) = h(n))$. We must show that $Y=P$. First $1 \in Y$ since $f(1) = c = h(1)$. Second, assume $n \in Y$, and let $f$ and $h$ be $S(n)$-admissible. By($\textrm{I}$), $f$ and $h$ are $n$-admissible. Hence, since $n \in Y$, it follows that $f(n) = h(n)$. Then, by (4), $f(S(n)) = g(f(n)) = g(h(n)) = h(S(n))$. Thus, $S(n) \in Y$. We have shown that $n \in Y \Rightarrow S(n) \in Y$. Hence, by mathematical induction, P=Y.

- $\textrm{IV})$ For any $n$ in $P$, by virtue of ($\textrm{II}$), we may take some $n$-admissible function $f$.

Let us define $F(n) = f(n)$. By ($\textrm{III}$), the value of $F(n)$ doest not depend upon the particular choice of the $n$-admissible function $f$.

It is obvious that the domain of $F$ is $P$. Also $F(1)$ = $f(1)$ for some $1$-admissible function $f$. But $f(1)=c$. Hence, we have condition (a):$F(1)=c$.

In addition, $F(S(n)) = f(S(n))$ for some $S(n)$-admissible function $f$. Since $f$ is also $n$-admissible, by virtue of ($\textrm{I}$), $F(n)=f(n)$. But, since $f$ is $S(n)$-admissible, $f(s(n)) = g(f(n))$. This yields (b): $F(S(n)) = g(F(n)).$

Thus conditions (a), (b) on the function $F$ are satisfied. We must still show that the range of $F$ is included in $W$. For any $n$ in $P$, $F(n) = f(n)$ for some $n$-admissible function $f$. Since $Range(f) \subseteq W$, it follows that $F(n) \in W$.

**Uniqueness.** Assume $F_1$ and $F_2$ are functions from $P$ into $W$ satisfying condition (a), (b). Let $K = \{n : n \in P \land F_1(n)=F_2(n)\}$. Now, $1 \in K$, since $F_1(1) = c = F_2(1)$. Moreover, if $n \in K$, then $F_1(n) = F_2(n)$. Hence, $F_1(S(n)) = g(F_1(n)) = g(F_2(n)) = F_2(S(n))$, that is, $S(n) \in K$. We have shown that $n \in K \Rightarrow S(n) \in K$. Hence, by mathematical induction, $P=K$. Thus, $F_1(n) = F_2(n)$ for all $n$ in $P$. Since $P$ is the domain of both $F_1$ and $F_2$, it follows that $F_1 = F_2$. $\blacksquare$

Let me know if Im reading this concept in the right way, from what I have understood the author take some $n$ of $P$ and specify a restriction of  the function $F$ to the function $f$ which satisfy the six listed conditions. So when satysfing those conditions the function is called $n$-admissible.

Thus if the function is $n$-admissible, then the function holds property (a) and partially holds property (b), but by the fact that exist a $n$-admissible function for every $n$ in $P$ and $F$ is defined as $F(n)=f(n)$ then $F$ hold property (b) for all $n$ in $P$.

I tried to found other usage of the concept of $n$-admissible, but it dont seem to be very common, there are a few examples following.

**edit 1**
It dont seems to be very common, I was trying to found other usage by searching for the same term, I found out this document [C Ring Project](http://www.libermath.org/CRingProject/pdf/CRingProject.pdf) which mentions admissible function at page 50, but it takes the definition from Mendelson who is the author of the book Im following.

Some books seems to use "n-admissible" definition too, as examples we have

[The Number Systems Of Analysis](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=b5RIDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA70&lpg=PA70&dq=%22n-admissible%20function%22&source=bl&ots=-VGD8arnxA&sig=ACfU3U1KHqT3u_gnGIMUTZY48WxejbAV8w&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiTzeOQpevqAhWXD7kGHeuGBiIQ6AEwCXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22n-admissible%20function%22&f=false) and [Theory of Radicals](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=KszSBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA161&lpg=PA161&dq=%22n-admissible%20function%22&source=bl&ots=61hiJ0UrOh&sig=ACfU3U00Kq11W9LkoPuBRxn3o6E5PUVtFQ&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiTzeOQpevqAhWXD7kGHeuGBiIQ6AEwBHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22n-admissible%20function%22&f=false)

Comment: The way you wrote it, you're close, but slightly misunderstanding. During the proof, we do not yet have an $F$ that we could restrict, so you'd have to throw in a couple of "hypothetical" there. If we had the additional condition $S(n) \notin A$, then an $n$-admissible function would be a function that could be a restriction of such an $F$ to the initial segment $I_n := \{1, \dotsc, n\}$ of $P$. Since $A$ might be a larger segment, a function is $n$-admissible if its restriction to $I_n$ could be the restriction of such an $F$. The conditions make the "could be" precise.

Comment: Im a bit confused, because if we let some $f$ be a restriction of such an $F$ to the initial segment $I_n = \{1,...,n\}$ of $P$, where $S(n) \notin I$, but we have $1 \in I$, $I \subseteq P$, $n \in I$ and we can define $f$ to met the conditions to be $n$-admissible, but I cant see what will be the image from $f(n)$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're confused about. What do you mean by "the image from $f(n)$"?

Comment: I just did a big mistake, I was thinking about sucessor of $n$ instead of how $f(n)$ will be defined in case $S(n) \notin I$, but as long $n \neq 1$, we have that $(\exists !q)(n = S(q))$, thus $f(n) = f(S(q)) = g(f(q)$, and we have that $q \in I$, because the way $I$ was defined and because condition (4) too.

Sorry for this, Im new to abstract mathematics.

From your comment I wonder why the author dont restricted $S(n) \notin A$, can you see a good reason?

Comment: Can you submit you first comment as an answer? This explanation give a precise definition of what n-admissible is in the given context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote is not quite correct. During the proof we do not yet have an $F$ that we could restrict, thus one cannot "specify a restriction of the function $F$". But if one inserts the word "hypothetical" into that, then one gets a correct (albeit not yet precise) description of the concept. The underlying idea is that *if* a function $F$ with the desired properties exists, *then* the restrictions of $F$ to initial segments of $P$ must satisfy certain conditions. The concept of $n$-admissibility makes that precise.

Conditions 1-4 say that the domain $A$ of an $n$-admissible function $f$ is an initial segment of $P$ containing $n$. Condition 5 is property a), and condition 6 says property b) holds *as far as that makes sense*, that is, on the whole domain of $f$.

Altogether, these are the conditions a restriction of $F$, if such an $F$ exists, to an initial segment of $P$ containing $n$ must *necessarily* satisfy.

Then the proof goes on to show that there is a unique $F \colon P \to W$ with properties a) and b), and thus $n$-admissibility is also sufficient to characterise the restrictions of $F$ to initial segments of $P$.

That proof is a (maybe *the*, discounting trivial variations) standard proof of the iteration theorem. That the concept of $n$-admissibility doesn't seem very common is because many authors do not give it a name. One can use the idea without naming it. Having a name for it adds convenience at some points of the proof, but at the (not very high) cost of introducing a new name.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this concept, I bet this will help other newcomers in abstract mathematics.